# Locoroco game collision detection

Tags: math, physics, computational-geometry

Can anyone explain what is the math/physics behind this popular PSP game Locoroco. My understanding about this game collision mechanism is , the whole world is made with bezier curves? If yes - my question is how to build a such a huge endless level , character of these game I guess its blob physics? 
Is it tile based level? Please help where to start the research on this topic.

http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/2003/12/bezierCollision.php

[image]

Comment: This question is better asked on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: sure ,i will do. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex level/specific physics with some optimized triangulation algorithm would be my approach.

If you are looking into making a similar game as Locoroco I'd use google to get my answers. A fast search gave me this.

http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/587860